# Overload of the multiplier operator for the fraction class

Tags: c++, class

Could you explain me how to correctly multiply the fraction by the number? Tried to overload, but I get compiler error:

> binary operator `*` : the operator accepting the left operand of type
>   of the `SimpleFraction` is not found

```
class SimpleFraction 
{
static int findGcd(int a, int b)
{
    while (a&&b)
    {
        if (a > b)
            a %= b;
        else
            b %= a;

    }
    return (a == 0) ? b : a;
}

private:
int a,
    b;
public:
SimpleFraction(int a1 = 0, int a2 = 1) :a(a1), b(a2) 
{
    if (a2 == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("zero division error");
}

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&out, const SimpleFraction& f)
{
    return out << f.a << "/" << f.b ;
}

friend istream& operator >> (istream&in, SimpleFraction& f) 
{
    char t;
    return in >> f.a >>t>> f.b;
}

friend SimpleFraction operator *(const SimpleFraction&x, int n) 
{
    int a = x.a *n;
    int gcd = finGcd(a, x.b);
    return SimpleFraction(a / gcd, x.b / gcd);
}
};
```

I get that error message , when I enter such code

```
int main()
{
SimpleFraction SFArray1(2, 2);
SimpleFraction r = SFArray1 * 2;
cout << r;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org).  As is I do not see how you get that error message.

Comment: You have a typo in `int gcd = finGcd(a, x.b);` but after fixing that I [cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52b804f6095c7491) the error

Comment: Does the answer not help? @choko

Comment: @SantiagoVarela it helped. Thank you)

Comment: Cool! Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
friend SimpleFraction operator *(const SimpleFraction&x, int n)
```

You don't need to use the `friend` keyword here. The operator * should be overloaded as part of the class. Your function signature should look something like this:

```
SimpleFraction operator *(const SimpleFraction& rightOperand) const {
/* ...implementation which should use values of "this" and rightOperand and return a newly instantiated SimpleFraction*/
    SimpleFraction result(this->a * rightOperand.a, this->b * rightOperand.b);
    return result;
}
```

### Update after OP edit

Looking at your code in main, you would have to do another overload with a int value like so:

```
SimpleFraction operator *(const int& rightOperand) const {
    SimpleFraction result(this->a * rightOperand.a, this->b); // I'm guessing you take "a" as a numerator  
    return result;
}
```

Furthermore, in your `main()` function you use `SimpleFraction` **= operator**. So you should implement the `operator=` function as well as the **Copy Constructor** as per the [**Rule of Three**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: _"implementation which should manipulate this"_ `operator*` should _never_ modify `this`.

Comment: @tuple_cat I was finishing editing. That's what I meant to say.

Comment: If `operator*` doesn't modify `this` it should be `const`.

Comment: plus 1 for **const correctness**. You're right. @tuple_cat